# Reduce security from views folder MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In my views folder i want to use templates from jsrender but when i try to access anything from the Views folder it gives me 404 and 500 error as response not found.

What i just want to do is to access *. HTML file from the Views folder.

What should be the change in Web.Config of Views?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What i just want to do is to access *. HTML file from the Views folder

No, you can't. The Views folder has a special meaning in ASP.NET MVC and there's a handler which forbids access to any file in it. You just have to put your templates somewhere else. A `~/Templates` folder doesn't seem like a bad idea.

Comment: I want to associate my views with the templates. Like if i have a Product folder in the Views folder i would like to invoke all product templates in there. That would be good way to manage my big application. Isn't that possible?

Comment: No, that's not possible. You could still have the same folder structure in the `~/Templates` directory though to organize them.